# Plug-in (Slickr Flickr) works on local machine, but not server

Tags: plugins, errors, server, local-installation

I am running Wordpress (3.1.4) with Slickr Flickr (1.3.2). I built a theme on top of thematic (0.9.7.7).

Everything seems to work fine on my local machine and I can render Slickr Flickr galleries in the them templates without issue.

However, when I enable the plug in on our server I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /home/amsfcom/public_html/2011/wp-content/plugins/slickr-flickr/slickr-flickr-oauth.php on line 5
```

I saw a few questions with answers that seemed to be due to PHP 4 and protected methods. I don't think this is the issue because the server uses PHP version 5.2.9 on Linux. Locally I am using a Mac with PHP version 5.2.15. Could this difference cause the problems?

Is there a way I can start to track down why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is down to your site running PHP4.

I suspect that your server has both PHP5 and PHP4 installed and happens to running PHP4 on this site.

You can verify this by uploading a file version.php to your web root folder containing the following PHP command

`<?php echo phpversion(); ?>`

Regards

Russell

Comment: Your totally right. In my server dashboard it shows 5, but PHP is using 4. Found a way to do it through the site dashboard, but it looks like I can force it with adding to the htaccess file for the directory. Thanks!